# Give directories nicknames in Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am currently using SSH-Remote add-on for VisualStudioCode and some directories are having numbered names due to docker usage, my question is:

"Can i somehow 'rename' them without actually making changes to directory name"

With this i would give folder a nickname or a alias shown only to me and not changing actual values on my VPS

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can add those folders to a workspace in VS Code, save the workspace and then edit the .code-workspace file you just saved to add a new node "name" where you can add custom names to the folder without actually renaming them.

```
{   
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "../path/to/your/directory1"
    },
    {
      "path": "../path/to/your/directory2"
    }
  ],
  "settings": {}
 }
```

from this to

```
{   
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "../path/to/your/directory1",
      "name": "Your Custom NickName1"
    },
    {
      "path": "../path/to/your/directory2",
      "name": "Your Custom NickName2"
    }
  ],
  "settings": {}
}
```